# Does asp.net mvc windows authntication works with workgroup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I have an asp.net mvc 5 web application that uses windows authentication.  i am currently the users can login to the application without entering user name and password, since they login to their machines using their Active directory username/password.

but my question is whether asp.net mvc windows authentication can work with workgroups or it can only work against active directory ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a workgroup, Windows Auth will work with the local users/groups defined on the server.

Comment: so if my asp.net mvc is using windows authentication, and i want to deploy it to a small business customer who use workgroup instead of active directory. Then my asp.net mvc can still be accessed using the workgroup username/password ?

Comment: There's no such think as a workgroup username/password. When a machine isn't joined to the domain, for the purposes of Windows AuthN, the source is the local SAM database on the server itself.